# Creating a plot of groundstate energy (for a set distance) against noise

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, noise

I am trying to create a plot of groundstate energy against noise like mentioned in the title.

I do this in the aim of finding some sort of correlation between the two meaning I can find what the energy would be with no noise and see if this is close to the actual value.

So far I have used the groundstate energy for H2 and used different noisey backends for example: FakeMelbourne, FakeLondon etc.

[image]

My question is, can I simulate noise a different way instead of using specific backends with noise already in them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build you own custom noise model for Aer - see https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/3_building_noise_models.html

Comment: Thankyou this makes a lot of sense.